# UI test : Wait for user input while running an instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-espresso

Is it possible to wait for user input like users mobile no or otp in an instrumentation test. I can hard code the mobile no. but the otp is not in my control. If its not possible how should we test such flows?

Comment: If that's an instrumentation test, why should there be a user? [`typeText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#typeText(java.lang.String)) is the method you need.

Comment: I assume you are testing authentication. Can you mock the authentication code? If not you could use UI Automation (https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html)

Comment: I was thinking of mocking the authentication, but my question was would it be possible to have some steps manual in the middle of the automation tests? Say for example by automation I can enter the mobile nos, now if the sim is on the same device I receive the otp and the test succeeds but now if I were to run the same test on an emulator i would have to enter the otp manually? Is this allowed in the middle of the test?

Comment: @azizbekian the otp comes at runtime, so I don't have control over it like I have over nos. but ya after reading a bit I think I will have to have a dummy user no for whom the otp will always be same, in that way my test will run its full course without depending on the backend